# How to generate .qmg animation programatically?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to generate .qmg file from bunch of PNGs to create boot animation for Samsung Android phones.

I have seen lots of methods that uses Samsung theme designer to convert pngs to .qmg

But I need to generate it programatically (in Android application for example).

Does anybody know specification of qmg format or maybe working code sample?

**Link 1:** https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=792953

**Link 2:** https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2189934

Comment: You can use ffmpeg lib for this.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper could you provide more info? I didn't find any info about ffmpeg qmg creation